# Best in wall electric heaters to replace Cadet HW078

Tags: hvac, heating

my condo came with Cadet HW078 heaters installed throughout.  There are 4 total: 1 in each bedroom and then 2 in main living room area.  Total size of the place is 1084 square feet.  I live in San Francisco so it doesn't ever get *too* cold, but it is nice to have heat as needed throughout the year.

Unfortunately, these Cadets suck.  They make my electric bill prohibitively expensive (200-300 month more than normal when I run them) and they don't even do a very good job, especially the two heating the main room.  I bought a simple space heater from costco and it does a way better job heating the room.

Since this is a condo, I am not permitted to do things like install a mini split heat pump, unfortunately.

Does anyone have a suggestion on good in wall electric heaters that I could replace the Cadets with that would do a better job heating the place without having an outrageous electric bill?  And would replacing these with a better model be something I could do as a DIY project, or should I hire a professional?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. Your second question is completely subjective and not for us to say.

Comment: The second question has a very definite answer, *actually,* since a condo is a MDU.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you address with your condo association how to install mini-splits, all electric heaters are exactly the same efficiency - 100% - but given the price of electricity and the ability to get 300-500% efficiency from heat pumps, it's not great, actually.

A toaster, an electric oven, a wall heater, and a room heater are all the same in terms of BTUs out per Kilowatt•hour in = 3412. For that matter, so is a crypto-currency mining computer, so you could set up a few of those that you turn on depending on the need for heat ;-) That would give you heat and something additional for the same electricity. Which the toaster and oven also do, to be fair.

In the current era, it would be well worth raising a fuss at the condo owner's association meeting (or corrupting other owners' minds before the meeting, to raise the odds of getting it to pass) to make it possible for all of the condo owners to be able to install heat pumps, considering the large power savings they provide over "toaster heat."

Since a condo is a Multiple Dwelling Unit, you need a Licensed Electrician to do electrical work such as replacing your heaters.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!  Is it at all possible that the in-wall space heaters are not directing the full output of their heat into the room?  For example installed incorrectly or losing heat into the wall or the neighboring condo unit?

Answer (score 4):

### You can't get something for nothing

At the end of the day, 1 kilowatt-hour is 3410 BTUs.  A 1500 watt heater makes 5120 BTUs/hour whether it's in-wall, baseboard, radiant, radiator, heater-fan, floor heat, oven, or a bitcoin miner - all electric heaters give exactly the same heat.

Electric heating is 100% efficient, full stop. There's nowhere else for the energy to go, and it has to go somewhere.  In fact, unless you have a laser aimed out a window, all electricity consumed inside the house turns to heat inside the house.   No matter what else you do with electricity, entropy turns it into heat.  And the efficiency is always dead nuts 100% in that capacity.

So there is NO answer to "I want an electric heater that is more efficient and doesn't beat me to death with electric bills". Period. End of subject.

The CostCo heater differs only in *your perception of* the heat - it's blowing air your way, or radiating IR, or doing whatever it's doing to make the heat *feel* better.  But it does not move the thermostat at all.  It's still the same heat in the end.  But don't take my word on it, try it.

### ... unless you use a physics "cheat code"

Because it turns out, by boiling a fluid in one place, and condensing it in another, we can actually move heat from one place to another, and it takes far less energy than the heat that is moved!

Heat pumps will do what you're looking for.  Yes, I know you said "no A/C", but a heat pump is often called a reverse cycle air conditioner.  It can move heat a from outdoors at as much as a 6:1 efficiency.

In full disclosure I must say they don't always work that well.  In arctic cold conditions their efficiency may fall as low as 2x, or even below that.  So while it should perform superlatively in a San Francisco winter, I can't make any promises about a San Francisco summer :)

*"The coldest winter I ever spent was a summer in San Francisco" - Mark Twain*

Answer (score 2):

The in wall cadets are simply space heaters that fit in the wall. All electric space heaters have the same efficiency, the existing ones can't be less efficient than the new ones you bought.

However you may prefer the spot where the portable ones are blowing, for example if you direct it at your feet while working. That's not technically more efficient, but concentrating heating where you sit may be more comfortable with less heating.